# What is the best libary for making a diagram and charts in Java?

Tags: java, charts, export, diagram

I have a programm that collects a lot of information and I want to export all this data in form of diagram and/or charts (as a pdf would be preference). What would be the method/libary of your choice to do so?

Comment: (i) find a charting library which has an export facility (most can export to png for example) (ii) find an image -> pdf converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jfreechart http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/ for creating charts and converting into diagrams.

If you want to use 3d charts probably you can try jzy3d.